# Azure DevOps Sever to Services Migration Time Longer for ProductionRun?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

A few days ago I successfully completed a DryRun for our organization's migration from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services and it took ~12 hours. Last night I kicked off the ProductionRun migration and it's currently still on Step 1 of 7 after 14 hours. Does anyone know if this is normal? Does the ProductionRun typically take longer? I was hoping it would be ready by this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not determinate consuming time for ProductionRun migration or DryRun. And the consuming time will be impacted by many factors, such as the collection database size, server queue wait, and service events, etc.

Thus we cannot guarantee that ProductionRun migration should also be completed within 12 hours as your mentioned DryRun.

In addition, you could monitor [Azure DevOps Status history page](https://status.dev.azure.com/_history), to know the latest service report. If currently there is service event in region of your target organization, the migration would be delayed. Also if there is service deployment in the same region, the migration would be delayed.

BTW, supposed that you encounter unexpected failed migration, you could follow this doc: [Migrate data from Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-overview?view=azure-devops) to migrate to Azure DevOps again. Also you could file a new ticket [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21) and provide the failed import identifier, the support engineer will contact the product group to check it in the backend and investigate the detailed failed logs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Since there's no documentation on proposed timetables for migration, I was attempting to use the DryRun as a baseline for determining how long or org would be down. Do you know if there are plans to include more detailed information in the future? Such as the progress of the individual step? Thanks again!

Comment: The product group might consider this feature if it is advised by many customers. Thus you could submit this suggestion [here](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=22), that will allow you to directly interact with the product group, and help the product group gathers customer's feedback.
BTW, if my answer helps, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.